# How to declare an array of structure and access (write to/read from) individual fields in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I'm trying to declare a structure in Matlab:

```
book = struct('name', '', 'author','', 'price,'', 'date_of_pub','')

num_books = input('enter number of books')
```

And then declare an array (list_of_books) containing those information  on a number (num_books) of books.

In C, I would do something like this (sample code, not going into detail)

```
typedef struct {
char name[20];
char author[20];
float price;
date date_of_pub; //'date' being another predefined struct containing dd, mm, yy
}book;

int main()
{
int num_books = 0;

printf("enter number of desired books\n");
scanf("%d", &num_books);

book *list_of_books = malloc(num_books * sizeof(book));

for(i = 0; i < num_books; ++i){
    printf("enter name of book #%d:\n",i+1);
    scanf("%s", list_of_books[i].name);
    //same for the other info
}
```

/* another loop to print out the information on books, this could be a separate function etc */

I know of http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html, but I'm looking for samples of Matlab code with similar implementations to learn from. Or if you have any other resources I could look into, with code samples, would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: And the array should also have empty values in all fields?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I want to implement a "for loop" going through the array and let the user fill in each field of the struct.

Comment: Oh. I got your question wrong then

Answer (score 1):

To create an array `list_of_books` containing `num_books` copies of `book`, simply use [`repmat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
list_of_books = repmat(book, num_books, 1);
```

---

To do it directly (without having defined `book` first):

```
book = struct('name',repmat({''},num_books,1), 'author','', 'price','', 'date_of_pub','');
```

The latter uses the syntax multiple-value systax of [`struct`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) (emphasis added by me):

> `S = struct(field1',VALUES1,'field2',VALUES2,...)`
>
> creates a structure array with the specified fields and values.  The value
>       arrays `VALUES1`, `VALUES2`, etc. must be **cell arrays of the same
>       size, scalar cells or single values. Corresponding elements of the
>       value arrays are placed into corresponding structure array elements**.
>       The size of the resulting structure is the same size as the value
>       cell arrays or 1-by-1 if none of the values is a cell.

Note that it suffices to give multiple values to one field (I've used the first in this case), and the others get automatically replicated.

Comment: Thank you. I'll need a for loop (for i=1:num_books) and ask the user to individually fill in each field of the struct for each book in the array. Tried with liste_of_books(i).name = input ('enter name of book') but it's failing. Any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: You need the flag `'s'` in `input` to accept string input: `list_of_books(i).name = input ('enter name of book: ', 's')`

Comment: Thank you! Pushing my luck further here, can "input" be formated? like list_of_books(i).name = input ('enter name of book number %d: ', i, 's') or is that not possible with "input"?

Comment: You can't do that directly. But the first argument of `input` can be the result of `sprintf` (as in C). So: `list_of_books(i).name = input(sprintf('enter name of book number %d: ', i), 's')`

Comment: Awesome thank you a lot for indulging me and the great helpful answers.